# How to use mypy with my local lambda functions in PyCharm

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pycharm, mypy, aws-sam

My goal is to use `mypy updateEc2Ddb.py`  command in my terminal window for my lambda function. I want to check typing in my lambda function using mypy, but when I run the command from the console from the console I get **error** like this: **'project_name' is not a valid Python package name**. My IDE is PyCharm, I have a SAM application and you can see hierarchy of folders below and I am testing lambda function locally with the 'sam invoke' command.

[image]

Comment: What is SAM? Surely you don't mean Simple Asynchronous Messaging the PHP framework, as the question's tags suggest? Please add more details, including the full error message/traceback and directory structure [as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: @InSync SAM is serverless application model, it is CloudFormation framework or superset

Comment: SAM is likely AWS SAM ([AWS Serverless Application Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html))